# Software Install Policy Not Applying to Terminal (Remote Desktop) Services Server

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, remote-desktop

I have a Google Chrome software install group policy object that works perfectly except when logging into the the Terminal (Remote Desktop) Services Server.

It's configured under "User Configuration" in Group Policy.

The group policy is linked to both my Employee OU, which contains the user account that is logging into the RDS server, and directly under the Domain, but it refuses to be acknowledged.  Why?

Comment: On your terminal server, you should almost certainly be using a COMPUTER policy...  Can you explain why you would be trying to do this per-user?

Comment: That was just simply how I was advised. :/  Even so, would not the logic of the user with the group policy applied to them logging into a domain connected computer invoke the policy?

Comment: All right, perfect.  Seeing how it works now, per user was indeed idiotic.  Thanks.